# Localizable.strings error - compiler says file is missing

Tags: objective-c, ios, localization, localizable.strings

I tried adding a Localizable.strings file and add some strings to test with, everything works fine.

However, when I try to add a localization things starts to get weird. I am able to add a localization (english and russian) and I can see in finder that the files are listed in the two folders; ru.lproj and en.lproj.

When I clean and build I get the following compilation error:

```
Copy .strings file Error
The file "Localizable.strings" couldn't be opened because there is no such file.
```

Comment: did u check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9359835/the-file-infoplist-strings-couldnt-be-opened?

Comment: Thanks. It wasn't that error, but it led me to investigate the .pbxproj file, where I found the error. Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Fixed it by a push in the right direction from this link provided by tiguero in the comment.

I looked further into the .pbxproj file and found this funky row, that looked fishy:

```
    6AAE55EC1551A42500C1F3F0 /* Localizable.strings */ = {isa = PBXFileReference; fileEncoding = 4; lastKnownFileType = text.plist.strings; path = Localizable.strings; sourceTree = "<group>"; };
```

I removed it, cleaned and rebuild. It is now replaced by the following line:

```
6AC473DC1624BF3E00503305 /* Localizable.strings in Resources */ = {isa = PBXBuildFile; fileRef = 6AC473DE1624BF3E00503305 /* Localizable.strings */; };
```

And it works!

Comment: If I could upvote more than once, then I would. Thanks for this.

Comment: Man, you just made my day!

Comment: I know this was some time ago, but I have the same issue now, can someone tell me, where I can find the .pbxproj file?

Comment: @FrederikWitte: Right-click on your `.xcodeproj` file, choose "Show package content" (or similar). Then there you have your `.pbxproj` file.